# incorrect syntax error CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in the batch

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK so here's my code trying to create a view but it keeps on telling me create view must only be the only statement in the batch tried everything need help

```
CREATE VIEW  [Vendors List] 
AS
    SELECT 
        VendorID, 
        SUM(InvoiceTotal) AS [YTD Invoice Total], 
        SUM(PaymentTotal) AS [YTD Payment Total], 
        SUM(CreditTotal) AS [YTD Credit Total]
    FROM 
        dbo.Invoices
    GROUP BY 
        VendorID
```

Comment: Please `GO` on a line before the `CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why not post your answer as an answer? Then this won't be in unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Many useful statements in SQL Server have to be at the beginning of a batch.  These include `create trigger`, `create stored procedure`, and many others.

What is a batch?  It is basically a unit of compilation.  It also limits the scope of local variables.  I advise you to read about batches in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx).

The simplest way to start a batch is to use `GO`.  Sometimes, you might want to put a statement in the middle of a block of code and you cannot use `GO` (say, in the body of a stored procedure).  This that case, you would use dynamic SQL instead.